# Bond Dissociation Energy in Water

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, energy

Why do the bond dissociation energies of the O−H bonds in water differ? Is it related to an increase in lone pair-bond pair repulsions upon the breaking of the first O−H bond (decrease in stability, so lesser energy is required to break the bond)?

Bond dissociation energy of the first O−H bond: 502 kJ/mol

Bond dissociation energy of the second O−H bond: 427 kJ/mol

Comment: This has been asked here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/107378/bond-enthalpy-of-hydroxide/